# What's the difference between these two function type definitions?

Tags: haskell

For the following trivial function definitions:

```
printLength1::(Num a)=>String->a
printLength1 s = length s


printLength2::String->Int
printLength2 s = length s
```

Why are they not the same ? In what situations i should choose one over the other?

And i get this error for printLength1:

```
Couldn't match type `a' with `Int'
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for rpnc :: String -> a at test.hs:20:1
    In the return type of a call of `length'
    In the expression: length s
    In an equation for `rpnc': rpnc s = length s
```

I understand this error. But how can i fix this ?
I've already read some posts here about rigid type variable but still couldn't understand how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first type signature is more general. It means the result can be any `Num`--it is polymorphic on its return type. So the result of your first function could be used as an `Int` or an `Integer` or any other `Num` instance.

The problem is that `length` returns an `Int` rather than any `Num` instance. You can fix this using `fromIntegral`:

```
printLength1 :: Num a => String -> a
printLength1 s = fromIntegral $ length s
```

Note that the signature of `fromIntegral . length` (which is the point-free version of the code above) is `Num c => [a] -> c`. This matches the signature you specified for your `printLength1` function.

Comment: Thanks guys. I hope there are no more such quirks hidden in the language.

Comment: @osager This isn't a quirk, this is a very fundamentally important part of the type system.  Polymorphic types (at least rank-1 polymorphic types) are turned into concrete types by how they are used.  If you write a type signature that claims that a type is polymorphic, it needs to actually *be* polymorphic.

Comment: The `Num` class isn't a quirk, but you could reasonably argue that `length` being an `Int` rather than a `Num a` is a quirk.

Comment: `Data.List.genericLength` has the type `Num a => [b] -> a`

Comment: @Grazer: That's good to know. The fact that there had to be a special generic version of `length` just goes to show that it is a bit of a quirk.

Answer (score 7):

Quoting [LearnYouAHaskell.com](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions):

> Note: This function has a type of numLongChains :: Int because length returns an Int instead of a Num a for historical reasons. If we wanted to return a more general Num a, we could have used fromIntegral on the resulting length.